# Group_concat with Query builder laravel

Tags: sql, laravel, mariadb, query-builder, laravel-5.5

Hello! , i have an issue with an sql Call on laravel 5.5 using query builder. when i do this

```
    $result = DB::table(self::$TABLA_COMPONENTE)
        ->join(self::$TABLA_ARCHIVOS ,self::$TABLA_COMPONENTE.'.com_id','=',self::$TABLA_ARCHIVOS.'.com_id')
        ->select(self::$TABLA_COMPONENTE.'.*',DB::raw('group_concat('.self::$TABLA_ARCHIVOS.'.ar_url) as com_archivos'))
        ->where(self::$TABLA_COMPONENTE.'.com_id',$id)->first();
```

i get the following error

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1140 Mixing of GROUP columns (MIN(),MAX(),COUNT(),...) with no GROUP columns is illegal if there is no GROUP BY clause (SQL: select `componente`.*, group_concat(archivos.ar_url) as com_archivos from `componente` inner join `archivos` on `componente`.`com_id` = `archivos`.`com_id` where `componente`.`com_id` = 2 limit 1)

this is the raw sql i get by using ->toSql()

```
This is the sql with ->toSql()

"select `componente`.*, group_concat(archivos.ar_url) as com_archivos from `componente` inner join `archivos` on `componente`.`com_id` = `archivos`.`com_id` where `componente`.`com_id` = ?
```

And it works fine on Phpmyadmin.

i also tried using Group by with no luck.

If you could help me with a solution I would be very grateful!

Answer (score 0):

This is actually mysql problem not laravel problem. Try add

```
->groupBy(self::$TABLA_COMPONENTE . '.id')
```

to you query.

EDITED: something like this one :

```
$result = DB::table(self::$TABLA_COMPONENTE)
    ->join(self::$TABLA_ARCHIVOS ,self::$TABLA_COMPONENTE.'.com_id','=',self::$TABLA_ARCHIVOS.'.com_id')
    ->select(self::$TABLA_COMPONENTE.'.*',DB::raw('group_concat('.self::$TABLA_ARCHIVOS.'.ar_url) as com_archivos'))
    ->groupBy(self::$TABLA_COMPONENTE . '.id')
    ->where(self::$TABLA_COMPONENTE.'.com_id',$id)->first();
```

note : it is not testet

Comment: Thanks for the response but it doesn't work too! 

->groupBy(self::$TABLA_COMPONENTE . '.com_id')

SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 'bd_empresa.componente.com_nombre' isn't in GROUP BY (SQL: select `componente`.*, group_concat(archivos.ar_url) as com_archivos from `componente` inner join `archivos` on `componente`.`com_id` = `archivos`.`com_id` where `componente`.`com_id` = 5 group by `componente`.`com_id` limit 1)